# Using Logarithmic Properties to simplify a quotient?

Tags: calculus

[image]

Simplify $$g(x)=\frac{(\tan^3x)}{e^{3x^3}x^7}.$$
I've tried simplifying this function using the properties of the natural logarithm, but no matter how I format it, it will not accept my answer as correct.

I know that $\ln(a/b)= \ln(a)-\ln(b)$, as well as that $\ln(ab)=\ln(a)+\ln(b)$, my answer to the question so far is..

$$[\ln(\tan(x)^3), 3x^3, 7\ln(x)]$$

As far as I know that is exactly what the question is asking, so I was wondering what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remember your negatives!

Comment: I think you are missing a negative sign for 2nd and 3rd Function.

Comment: Right! My bad, I put in the negatives but it's still saying I have the wrong answer, could it be something to do with the absolute value signs?

Comment: @AlexCharron: Note that when $\tan(x)>0$, you could do one more step ahead. In fact $\ln(\tan^3(x))$ becomes $3\ln(\tan(x))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}\ln|g(x)|&=\ln(\tan^3x)-\ln(e^{3x^3}x^7) \\ 
\ln|g(x)|&=3\ln(\tan x)-3x^3\ln(e)-7\ln(x) \\
\ln|g(x)|&=3\ln(\tan x)-3x^3-7\ln(x)\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thanks! I didn't take the power out of the logarithm for tan(x)^3, that's what I was forgetting. Also I had to be sure that everything inside the ln's on the right hand side were absolute value as well, because of the domain restrictions of f=ln(x). Thanks again.